# Compiler ask for header i have on my main file

Tags: c, include

i have 2 c files and h file.
the main file got the library on it and my compiler also asks me to put it in the other file.

why is that?

```
note: ‘assert’ is defined in header ‘<assert.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <assert.h>’?
1 | #include <stddef.h>
+++ |+#include <assert.h>
```

edit the files looks like that.

fucn.c

```
void func(int x)
{
       .....asert(x == y) ....
}
```

file.h

```
#ifndef FILE
#define FILE

void func(int x);

 #endif
```

main_c.c

```
#include <assert.h>
#include "file.h"
.
.
.
func(int x)
.
.
```

if im including <assert.h> in the main file why i also need to include it in the func.c file?

Comment: It may have something to do with the contents of the file. There's no way for us to tell without seeing those. See also: [mre]

Comment: So you are using `assert` somewhere in your program, so the compiler is suggesting to add the header it is defined in.

Comment: `#include <assert.h>` doesn't include the library, it adds whatever text is in it. It has to be added to each c file which needs those headers.